# Inconsistent completion for identical prompts and params with llama.cpp python and ctransformer

Tags: langchain, llama-cpp-python, llamacpp, ctransformers

I've been comparing various langchain compatible llama2 runtimes, using langchain llm chain.
Having the following parameter overrides:

```
# llama.cpp:
    model_path="../llama.cpp/models/generated/codellama-instruct-7b.ggufv3.Q5_K_M.bin",

    n_ctx = 2048,
    max_tokens = 2048,
    temperature = 0.85,
    top_k = 40,
    top_p = 0.95,
    repeat_penalty = 1.1,
    seed = 112358,

# ctransformer:
    model="../llama.cpp/models/generated/codellama-instruct-7b.ggufv3.Q5_K_M.bin",

    config={
        "context_length": 2048,
        "max_new_tokens": 2048,
        "temperature": 0.85,
        "top_k": 40,
        "top_p": 0.95,
        "repetition_penalty" :1.1,
        "seed" : 112358
    },
```

The model is derived from original codellama-7b-instruct, using methods suggested for llama.cpp.

The system and user prompts are the same. And the prompt template is from the codellama paper.

```
template = """<s>[INST] <<SYS>>
{system}
<</SYS>>

{user} [/INST]"""

system = """You are very helpful coding assistant who can write complete and correct programs in various programming languages, expecially in java and scala."""
```

The ctransformer based completion is adequate, but the llama.cpp completion is qualitatively bad, often incomplete, repetitive, and sometimes stuck in a repeat loop.

Apart from the overrides, I have verified that the defaults AFAIK are the same for both implementations.

What aspects can I check more, to bring llama.cpp to behave the same, since I'm more interested in using llama.cpp.